# No 'Advanced' option showing for sharing permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, error, administration, sharing

When I clink on sharing options, no 'Advanced' options appear so I can not get to the 'Stop Inheriting permissions' screen. Is it due to my device or a setting do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser you are using? Try to use another browser to test, compare the result.

Please check your permission.